# Best way to repair Neoprene gloves

Tags: repair, gloves

I have a pair of Castelli Neoprene gloves. They are just over a year old and one of them has a tear up one of the gauntlet sleeves and various smaller holes on the thumb, fingers and the palm.

All of the tears / holes appear to be along seam lines, which appear to be stitched, but not quite.

[image: SideTear] [image: ThumbHole]

**Would it be better to repair these tears by stitching, or gluing, I have seen some wetsuit glue that I assume can be used on Neoprene gloves**

Comment: My impression is that Castelli gear is very nice but is not as durable as other brands.  That may be because they're nice, they're also relatively lightweight.

Comment: @Criggie I've had the same experience

Answer (score 4):

I've got some wetsuit glue, and the join is really tough.  Just be sure to use it on clean, dry material,follow the instructions carefully (it's a bit like patch cement), and allow it to set for plenty of time before use.  Sadly, you can probably reckon on a nearby failure before too long, as the stress is moved to a different place.

I recommend keeping the glue in the freezer, sealed in a bag -- it keeps longer that way, so you should get another few uses out of it.

Comment: Good thought - its like a tube patch but try and use the biggest patch that will fit,  Ideally the patch will go all the way to the nearest stitched seam.   For added durability you can sew the patch on as well as sticking it.

Answer (score 2):

My favoured winter option for gloves is neoprene. When they inevitably start to tear - my preference is to stitch neoprene.

The best stitch I've found is to use is a wide stitch to pull the edges of the material together rather than small tight stitches. The stitching doesn't look pretty but makes for a more durable repair. I used a standard needle with doubled-up threading for a tougher stitch.

This link below might be helpful - and illustrates the wideness of the stitching used.
https://blog.cyberdaze.org/2011/01/02/sewing-neoprene/

Answer (score 0):

I've torn a bunch of Castelli stuff over the years. I just started using this ShoeGoo product and it's working well so far.

[image]

I've used it on a pair of gloves for a tear near the finger and it worked well.

Here is a a different glove, similar to the pair I used it on before. I'll be repairing the finger soon.

[image]

And this is what it looks like dried, on a synthetic fiber of a torn winter boot, for some context. It's somewhat like a pliable rubber cement. It smells extremely strong and volatile, ventilation is necessary. It dries within a couple hours.

I'd recommend it. I got a large tube for about 5 dollars on Amazon. I have no affiliation with the company. Happy gluing.

[image]

Comment: That might be a good option as I have a pair of Van trainers where the seam of the sole is coming off and I could use that glue for this as well